# Laravel calling other controller variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 files in laravel. One is *dashboard.blade.php* and *withdraw.blade.php*. Both have a controller for dashboard i.e. *dashboardcontroller* and similarly for withdraw *withdrawcontroller*. I have a variable in dashboardcontroller name `$approveMediatotal`. How do I reference it in *withdraw.blade.php*?

Comment: `return view('withdraw', ['approveMediatotal' => $approveMediatotal]);`

Comment: Then from the view, you can just simply do this: `{{$approveMediatotal}}`

Comment: Also, I highly recommend reading through the laravel documentation. It's thorough and a great resource to have.  http://laravel.com/docs

Comment: dude create the variable in both controllers andjust pass it to views

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `Session`

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
Session::get('key');
```

In **dashboardcontroller** :

```
Session::put('approveMediatotal', $approveMediatotal);
```

and then , in **withdrawcontroller** :

```
$res = Session::get('approveMediatotal');
return view('withdraw')->withApproveMediaTotal($res);
```

you can find more information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)

Comment: Thank You EveryOne. If we can do this thing. index.blade.php i have make a normal php variable can i call it in withdraw.blade.php. *Note: variable is not in controller now.

Comment: You can do that, but that's not good way ... when you have Laravel based php file, everything will be protect and cover by framework @AshikurRahman

Comment: your welcome ... accept the answer if it was helpful @AshikurRahman